# What does おこだわ mean on Twitter?

Tags: meaning

What does おこだわ mean on Twitter? I see it a lot but can't find a definition

Comment: Link some exmaples?

Answer (score 3):

おこ is the shortened form of the verb 怒る・おこる・to get angry, to get mad

So おこだわ is 怒ってる

(You can learn more about it, [here](https://meaning.jp/posts/508), it's all in japanese though)